# Visual studio 2010 - Class diagram with namespaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, class-diagram

How can I create class in specific folder (namespace) in my project,  and see the classes grouped by there namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Visual Studio Ultimate you can choose "Architecture" from the menu and generate a namespace diagram.

Once the diagram has rendered, you can expand the namespaces and other elements to show the classes they contain.

Note, specific folder != namespace.  New files in given folders are defaulted to the namespace, but from experience, try not to rely on it when working in a team or with someone elses' code. ;-)

Comment: But how can I build the project in this way, like Class Diagram can do? I mean that in Class Diagram I can add and change the project structure. So how can I do this things with some namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a class in the appropriate folder with the option Add new Item.

2) Drop the class in to the class diagram.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsclassdesigner/thread/bebfa1a4-1930-4a56-b0fc-e15a238650ac/